# open port 23 but not possible to access it

Tags: port, wifi, repeater, telnet, nmap

okay I just did a scan on the xiaomi repeater extender using nmap
and output like this:

> nmap 192.168.90.8 -Pn -sV

```
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-01-19 15:08 WIB
Nmap scan report for 192.168.90.8
Host is up (0.048s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed tcp ports (conn-refused)
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
23/tcp open  telnet?
1 service unrecognized despite returning data. If you know the service/version, please submit the following fingerprint at https://nmap.org/cgi-bin/submit.cgi?new-service :
SF-Port23-TCP:V=7.92%I=7%D=1/19%Time=61E7C71F%P=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu%r(NULL
SF:,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(GenericLines,41,"Login\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Na
SF:me\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:")%r(tn3270,18
SF:,"Login\x20as:\xff\xfd\x18\xff\xfd\x19\xff\xfb\x19\xff\xfd\0\xff\xfb\0"
SF:)%r(GetRequest,41,"Login\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:I
SF:nvalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:")%r(HTTPOptions,41,"Login\x20as:
SF:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin
SF:\x20as:")%r(RTSPRequest,41,"Login\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogi
SF:n\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:")%r(RPCCheck,9,"Login\x
SF:20as:")%r(DNSVersionBindReqTCP,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(DNSStatusRequestTCP,
SF:9,"Login\x20as:")%r(Help,25,"Login\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLog
SF:in\x20as:")%r(SSLSessionReq,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(TerminalServerCookie,9,
SF:"Login\x20as:")%r(TLSSessionReq,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(Kerberos,9,"Login\x
SF:20as:")%r(SMBProgNeg,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(X11Probe,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(F
SF:ourOhFourRequest,41,"Login\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as
SF::Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:")%r(LPDString,25,"Login\x20as:
SF:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:")%r(LDAPSearchReq,41,"Login\x20
SF:as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLo
SF:gin\x20as:")%r(LDAPBindReq,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(SIPOptions,13D,"Login\x2
SF:0as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nL
SF:ogin\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Na
SF:me\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid\x20Use
SF:r\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid
SF:\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:
SF:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin\x20as:Invalid\x20User\x20Name\r\nLogin
SF:\x20as:")%r(LANDesk-RC,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(TerminalServer,9,"Login\x20a
SF:s:")%r(NCP,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(NotesRPC,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(JavaRMI,9,"
SF:Login\x20as:")%r(WMSRequest,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(oracle-tns,9,"Login\x20
SF:as:")%r(ms-sql-s,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(afp,9,"Login\x20as:")%r(giop,9,"Lo
SF:gin\x20as:");

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 120.76 seconds
```

then when I want to access the open port, which is port 23/telnet I can't press enter in the login field, and this is what I get:

```
telnet 192.168.90.8
Trying 192.168.90.8...
Connected to 192.168.90.8.
Escape character is '^]'.
Login as:admin^M
```

you can see above that I tried to press the enter key after filling in the admin login, but instead it came out

```
 ^M
```

is there something wrong with the scan?
Or is that port not accessible?

Answer (score 0):

use python

```
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 11:40:36)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> from telnetlib import Telnet
>>> Telnet('192.168.90.8',23).interact()
```